# Minimum commands to reach an value

Tags: algorithms

Sorry if I am doing it wrong in some way.

Some days ago I have passed trough an technical test in which I had 3 tasks to complete. The tasks were a problem and I have to write an algorithm to solve it.

One of the 3 tasks I could not complete. Really, I have absolutly no idea how to start.

**I am not asking for ready algorithm here.**

I'll try to reproduce here.

---

```
Command 'X': X = ( 2 * X ) - Y
Command 'Y': Y = ( 2 * Y ) - X
Initial values: X = 0, Y = 1;
```

Given a N number, what's the minimum of commands where X or Y reach N. Each command change it's own value.

If I send the command 'X', the value of X will be '-1', and so on

The exemple was N = -11
Commands: 'X','X','Y','X', this way X will be equal -11.

```
Command 'X', X = ( 2 * 0 ) - 1 = -1  , Y = 1
Command 'X', X = ( 2 * ( -1) )  - 1 = -3  , Y = 1
Command 'Y', X = -3                  , Y = ( 2 * 1 ) - (-3) = 5
Command 'X', X = ( 2 * -3 ) - 5 = -11, Y =5
```

Comment: To start with a naive algorithm let me tell you that we can have a naive recursive exponential algorithm where we try out each combination by one function call trying command X and other command Y till we get the number. We have to think deeper for optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts about the task.

1. Let us start with reducing all power of 2 from N.
   If $N=2^kM$ then we can first apply $$Y=2Y-0$$ $k$ times.

Now you have new task of reaching smaller number $M$ starting with $X=0$ and $Y=1$.

2. $X\le 0$ and $Y>0$ holds after every transformation. So if $N$ is positive we will reach it with $Y$ and if $N \le 0$ we reach it with $X$.
3. Replacing $X$ with $X'=-X$ may help thinking.
   $$ X' \to 2X'+Y $$
   $$ Y \to 2Y+X' $$
   looks simpler and is equivalent to the original task.
4. Applying one operation $k$ times we get
   $$ Y \to 2^kY+(2^k-1)X' $$
5. Another nice representation of the operations:
   $$ X' \to X'+(X'+Y)$$
   $$Y \to Y + (X'+Y)$$
6. From 5. after $k$ steps sum of the numbers becomes $2^k$ and we actually add $2^{k-1}$ to one of numbers.
7. **Solution**. There is always only one way to reach $N$. Number of operations is $log_2N$. Imagine $N=101110001$ in binary form. Then we go from right to left and change X when there is 0 and Y when there is 1 in binary representation. In this way we finally construct $Y=101110001$ and almost inverted X=01000111**1**. There is only one peculiarity. When we start for the first bit Y is already 1 and we need to apply X transformation instead of Y.

Comment: Will it be minimal??

Comment: My gut tells me that we should eliminate powers of 2 first and solve the task for an odd N. Until we have a complete solution we cannot prove that it is an optimal step.

Comment: In this formula you are test for one case where all commands are `Y`?

Comment: Yes. To eliminate powers of 2 we use only Y commands. By the way, X is always less or equal 0 and Y is always positive. This feature is preserved after every operation. May be without loss of generality but for the convenience we may replace X with -X and get both formula easier to imagine.

Comment: Right. Also I thought that an option could be calculate backwards. We know ta X is always negative and Y is always positive. So `-11 = (2*X)-Y`. With the negative/positive constraint, can we assume that there will be only one solution on this equation?

Comment: Finally found a solution. I cannot imaging finding it during the stressed interview environment.

Comment: @IvanKovtun Thank you very much for all time you spent on this. I had only 30 minutes (90 for 3 tasks) to complete this. But I am sure that this task is to see if the candidate is able to think out of the box under stress. I really appreciate your help.